# Error:Node: 'bce_dice_loss/logistic_loss/mul' required broadcastable shapes

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I am working on a image segmentation problem where I am trying to combine UNet with some attention network but in the process of doing so I encountered this error:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
def create_unet(input_img):
#     input_img=Input(shape=(sze,sze,channel))
    c1 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
    c1 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c1)
    p1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c1)

    c2 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(p1)
    c2 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c2)
    p2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c2)

    c3 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(p2)
    c3 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c3)
    p3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c3)

    c4 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(p3)
    c4 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c4)
    p4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(c4)

    c5 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(p4)
    c5 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c5)

    u6 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c5)
    u6 = concatenate([u6, c4])
    c6 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(u6)
    c6 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c6)

    u7 = Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c6)
    u7 = concatenate([u7, c3])
    c7 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(u7)
    c7 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c7)

    u8 = Conv2DTranspose(16, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c7)
    u8 = concatenate([u8, c2])
    c8 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(u8)
    c8 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c8)

    u9 = Conv2DTranspose(8, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c8)
    u9 = concatenate([u9, c1], axis=3)
    c9 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(u9)
    c9 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c9)

    outputs = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), padding="same",activation='sigmoid')(c9)

#     model = Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=outputs)
    return outputs

image_size = 512
base_model = keras.applications.DenseNet121(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(image_size, image_size, 3))
base_in = base_model.input
base_out = base_model.output

last3 = base_model.get_layer('relu').output
last2 = base_model.get_layer('conv5_block16_0_relu').output
last1 = base_model.get_layer('conv5_block15_0_relu').output
# segmentation_output_1 = new_model(last3, last2, last1)
segmentation_output_2 = spatial_hierarchical(last3, last2, last1)
# print(segmentation_output_2.shape)
output = create_unet(segmentation_output_2)
output=Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(output)
# print(output.shape)
model = keras.Model(inputs=base_in, outputs=output)

# model.summary()
# print(output.shape)
# segmentation_output_3=Concatenate()([segmentation_output_1,segmentation_output_2])
```

This is my code for my model and I am getting this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[93], line 1
----> 1 train(40,1,3e-6,512)

Cell In[65], line 66, in train(num_epochs, batch_size, lr1, img_dim)
     62             model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=lr1),loss=bce_dice_loss,metrics=['accuracy',diceCoef,
     63                                                                                         jaccard_index,
     64                                                                                         tf.keras.metrics.Precision(), tf.keras.metrics.Recall()])
     65 #             history = model.fit(train_generator,steps_per_epoch=318//batch_size,validation_data=val_generator,validation_steps=318//batch_size,epochs=num_epochs)
---> 66             history = model.fit(train_generator,steps_per_epoch=training_samples_size//batch_size,
     67                     validation_data=val_generator,
     68                     validation_steps=val_samples_size//batch_size,
     69                     epochs=num_epochs,callbacks=[checkpoint])

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py:52, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     50 try:
     51   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     53                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     54 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     55   if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'bce_dice_loss/logistic_loss/mul' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 17, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 1043, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 728, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 195, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 603, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1909, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 513, in dispatch_queue
      await self.process_one()
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 502, in process_one
      await dispatch(*args)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 409, in dispatch_shell
      await result
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 729, in execute_request
      reply_content = await reply_content
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 422, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 540, in run_cell
      return super().run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3009, in run_cell
      result = self._run_cell(
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3064, in _run_cell
      result = runner(coro)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 129, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3269, in run_cell_async
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3448, in run_ast_nodes
      if await self.run_code(code, result, async_=asy):
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3508, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "/tmp/ipykernel_29/283950785.py", line 1, in <module>
      train(40,1,3e-6,512)
    File "/tmp/ipykernel_29/1394727156.py", line 66, in train
      history = model.fit(train_generator,steps_per_epoch=training_samples_size//batch_size,
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1685, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_step
      loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1109, in compute_loss
      return self.compiled_loss(
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 265, in __call__
      loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 142, in __call__
      losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 268, in call
      return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/tmp/ipykernel_29/1175749950.py", line 14, in bce_dice_loss
      loss = binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred) + diceCoefLoss(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 2156, in binary_crossentropy
      backend.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits),
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/backend.py", line 5707, in binary_crossentropy
      return tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(
Node: 'bce_dice_loss/logistic_loss/mul'
required broadcastable shapes
     [[{{node bce_dice_loss/logistic_loss/mul}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_551359]
```

Dce_lossfunction:

```
from tensorflow import reduce_sum
from tensorflow.keras import backend as  K
def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred, smooth=1):
    intersection = K.sum(y_true * y_pred)
    union = K.sum(y_true) + K.sum(y_pred)
    return K.mean( (2. * intersection + smooth) / (union + smooth), axis=0)

def dice_p_bce(in_gt, in_pred):
    return 0.01*binary_crossentropy(in_gt, in_pred) - dice_coef(in_gt, in_pred)
```

I did try to get the y_true and y_pred shapes still no output.

Tried many things still not working but running on unet alon not with some attention network.Why?